# how to prove $\mu(\limsup E_n\setminus \liminf E_n)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

$E_n$ is a sequence of measurable sets in finite measure space $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$. Then the  characteristic funtions $\chi_{E_n} $ converges in $L^2(\mu)$ if and only if $\mu(\limsup E_n\setminus \liminf E_n)=0$.

I have solved the necessary part . For the essential part, i,e to prove $\mu(\limsup E_n\setminus \liminf E_n)=0$. we know that $\mu( \liminf E_n)\leq\liminf\mu(  E_n)\leq\limsup\mu(  E_n)\leq\mu( \limsup E_n)$, if $\mu(E_n)<\infty, \forall n$.
I can only get that there is a characteristic function $\chi_E$ st $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\mu(E_n\Delta E)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int |\chi_{E_n}-\chi_E|^2=0$. how to show  $\mu(\limsup E_n\setminus \liminf E_n)=0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X = [0, 1)$ be equipped with the usual Lebesgue measure structure. Define

$$ E_{n,k} = [(k-1)/2^{n}, k/2^{n} ) \quad \text{for } 1 \leq k \leq 2^{n} $$

and re-enumerate this double sequence to form a sequence $\{E_{n}\}$. Then $\chi_{E_{n}} \to 0$ in $L^{2}$ but

$$ \limsup_{n\to\infty} E_{n} = [0, 1) \quad \text{and} \quad \liminf_{n\to\infty} E_{n} = \varnothing. $$

Therefore we have $\mu(\limsup E_{n} \setminus \liminf E_{n}) = 1$ and the claim is false.

Comment: Good counterexample!    $ E_{n,k} = [(k-1)/2^{n}, k/2^{n} ),1\leq k \leq 2^n, n=0,1,\cdots$